# tkinter: why is my login window not in the right position?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I made 2 windows: `main` & `login`.I want the button and login window in toplevel,but always jump into main,why? 
If I write code in poplogin() and not import module ,it works correct.

```
main.py
#! python3
from tkinter import *
from login import login

def demo():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("demo")
    root.geometry('640x400')  
    Button(root,text='login',width=10,command=poplogin).grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
    root.mainloop()

def poplogin():
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.grid()
    toplevel.title('login')
    login(toplevel)

if __name__ == "__main__":demo()
```

---

```
login.py
#! python3
from tkinter import *

class login(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.creat_login()

    def creat_login(self):
        Label(text='email').grid(row=1)
        user_email = Entry()
        user_email.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)

        Label(text='password').grid(row=2)
        user_password = Entry(show='*')
        user_password.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)  

        Button(text='login',width=10).grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    login().mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to use `parent` in widgets: `Entry(parent, ...)`, etc. If you don't use parent then `tkinter` use main window.

Comment: @furas it's OK thank U !!!

Comment: @furas I add right code at last,but I don't know why self.grid() looks no any effect ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to inform widget who is its parent - `Widget(parent, ...)`. If you don't do this then `tkinter` use main window.

In your code you have to use `self`

And you have to use `self.pack()` to show `Frame` in `Toplevel`

```
#! python3

from tkinter import *

class login(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.creat_login()

        # show in Toplevel
        self.pack()

    def creat_login(self):
        # self
        Label(self, text='email').grid(row=1)

        # self
        user_email = Entry(self)
        user_email.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        # self    
        Label(self, text='password').grid(row=2)

        # self
        user_password = Entry(self, show='*')
        user_password.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)  

         # self
        Button(self, text='login', width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login().mainloop()
```

Comment: thank u for your reply,I try your code,rise _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid,so I change self.pack() to self.grid(),but same result , always in main window.

Comment: you can't use at the same time `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()` in one window or frame. Always show full error message. Maybe problem is in different place or you have to change other pack() to grid() too.

Answer (score -1):

right code

```
from tkinter import *

class login(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.creat_login(parent)

        # With or without this line the same results,I don't know why 
        self.grid()

    def creat_login(self,parent):

        Label(parent, text='email').grid(row=1)

        user_email = Entry(parent)
        user_email.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        Label(parent, text='password').grid(row=2)

        user_password = Entry(parent, show='*')
        user_password.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)  

        Button(parent, text='login', width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login().mainloop()
```

Comment: it is place for answer, not for question. Add this to your question. And add full error message (Traceback) too.

Comment: this code can work ,so I post it. no any error message .

Comment: I saw comment in code and I thought it doesn't work. I see you use `parent` instead of `self` so you put directly in Toplevel so you could have problem with `pack()`. I use `self` so I put in `Frame`, not directly in Toplevel, so I could use `pack()`. You could describe difference.